# Test coverage fails to cover test written

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am writing a test using Jasmine for Angular 8 application. I have written test for confirmation dialog. I have three conditions to check while showing the confirmation dialog. Reset, Reject and Approve. At the moment when i am running npm test cover for test coverage , its highlighting that else part of the code below isn't covered. I thought my test  it('should call reject confirmation dialog) should have covered it.
I am not sure why tests aren't covering bit ? Could somebody help

```
if (type === 'Approve') {
  this.confirmationDialog.show(this.approvalMessage, type, () => this.confirm(type));
} else if (type === 'Reset') {
  this.confirmationDialog.show(this.resetMessage, type, () => this.confirm(type));
} else if (type === 'Reject') {
  this.confirmationDialog.show(this.rejectMessage, type, () => this.confirm(type));
}
```

Component code

```
export class ApproveComponent {
  public showMessage = false;
  public message: string;
  public body = 'Loading content for approval...';
  public loading = true;
  public permissions: NgxPermissionsObject;
  private id: string;
  private type: string;
  private approvalMessage = 'Are you sure the information is correct and you want to approve?';
  private resetMessage = 'Are you sure you want to reset this approval back to the start?';
  private rejectMessage = 'Are you sure you want to reject this approval? ' +
    'Rejecting an approval is permanent and will close this process and prevent it progressing further.';

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private service: ApprovalsService,
    private ngxPermissionsService: NgxPermissionsService,
    private messageService: MessageService,
    public confirmationDialog: ConfirmationDialogService) {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params['id'];
      this.type = params['type'];
      this.loading = true;
      this.service.get(this.type, this.id).then(x => {
        if (!x) { return; }
        this.loading = false;
        this.body = x.body;
      });
    });
    this.permissions = this.ngxPermissionsService.getPermissions();
  }




  public confirmation = (type: 'Reset' | 'Reject' | 'Approve') => {
    if (!this.showMessage
      && ((type === 'Approve' && this.permissions.ViewNotes)
        || (type !== 'Approve'))) {
      this.showMessage = true;
      return;
    }

    if (!this.message
      && ((type === 'Approve' && this.permissions.ViewNotes)
        || (type !== 'Approve'))) {
      this.messageService.add('Message is required.', 'warning');
      return;
    }

    if (type === 'Approve') {
      this.confirmationDialog.show(this.approvalMessage, type, () => this.confirm(type));
    } else if (type === 'Reset') {
      this.confirmationDialog.show(this.resetMessage, type, () => this.confirm(type));
    } else if (type === 'Reject') {
      this.confirmationDialog.show(this.rejectMessage, type, () => this.confirm(type));
    }

  }

  public confirm = (type: 'Reset' | 'Reject' | 'Approve') => {
    let promise;

    if (type === 'Reset') {
      promise = this.service.reset(this.id, this.type, this.message);
    } else if (type === 'Reject') {
      promise = this.service.reject(this.id, this.type, this.message);
    } else if (type === 'Approve') {
      promise = this.service.approve(this.id, this.type, this.message);
    }


    promise.then(() => {
      this.messageService.add(`Successfully ${type}.`, 'info');
      this.navigateToApprovalList();
    });
  }


  private navigateToApprovalList = () => this.router.navigate(['/approvals']);
}
```

Test component

```
describe('ApproveComponent', () => {
  let component: ApproveComponent;
  let injector: TestBed;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ApproveComponent>;
  const mockService: ApprovalsService = <ApprovalsService>{
    approve: (id: string, type: string, message: string) => <Promise<any>>{},
    reset: (id: string, type: string, message: string) => <Promise<any>>{},
    reject: (id: string, type: string, message: string) => <Promise<any>>{},
    get: (type: string, id: string) => <Promise<any>>{},
  };
  const mockRoute = { params: of({ id: '123', type: 'test' }), snapshot: {} };

  function setupComponent(getResult: any = {}) {
    spyOn(mockService, nameof<ApprovalsService>('approve')).and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({}));
    spyOn(mockService, nameof<ApprovalsService>('reset')).and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({}));
    spyOn(mockService, nameof<ApprovalsService>('reject')).and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({}));
    spyOn(mockService, nameof<ApprovalsService>('get')).and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(getResult));

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        DxTextAreaModule,
        DxButtonModule,
        SharedModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([{ path: 'approvals', component: ApproveComponent }])
      ],
      declarations: [ApproveComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: ApprovalsService, useValue: mockService },
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: mockRoute },
        { provide: MessageService, useClass: MockMessageService },
        { provide: ConfirmationDialogService, useValue: ConfirmationDialogServiceMock },
        { provide: NgxPermissionsService, useClass: MockNgxPermissionsService }
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ApproveComponent);
    injector = getTestBed();
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    spyOn((<any>component).router, 'navigate').and.returnValue(true);

    fixture.detectChanges();
  }

  it('should create and call get', () => {
    setupComponent();

    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    expect(mockService.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('should call get and do not set body on empty result', () => {
    setupComponent(null);

    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    expect(component.body).toBe('Loading content for approval...');
  });

  it('should call confirmation dialog when accept confirmation is called', () => {
    setupComponent();
    const dialogService = injector.get(ConfirmationDialogService);
    const dialogServiceSpy = spyOn(dialogService, 'show').and.callThrough();
    component.showMessage = true;
    component.message = 'Approved because potato';
    fixture.ngZone.run(() => component.confirmation('Approve'));
    expect(dialogServiceSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(dialogServiceSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });



   it('should call reject confirmation dialog', () => {
    setupComponent();
    const dialogService = injector.get(ConfirmationDialogService);
    const dialogServiceSpy = spyOn(dialogService, 'show').and.callThrough();

    component.showMessage = true;
    component.message = 'rejected because potato';
    fixture.ngZone.run(() => component.confirmation('Reject'));
    expect(dialogServiceSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mockService.reject).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('should call reset confirmation dialog', () => {
    setupComponent();
    const dialogService = injector.get(ConfirmationDialogService);
    const dialogServiceSpy = spyOn(dialogService, 'show').and.callThrough();

    component.showMessage = true;
    component.message = 'rejected because potato';
    fixture.ngZone.run(() => component.confirmation('Reset'));
    expect(dialogServiceSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mockService.reset).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('should set showMessage when reject is called', () => {
    setupComponent();

    component.showMessage = false;
    fixture.ngZone.run(() => component.confirmation('Reject'));
    expect(component.showMessage).toBe(true);
    expect(mockService.reject).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('should not call service when reject is called and message is empty', () => {
    setupComponent();

    component.showMessage = true;
    component.message = '';
    fixture.ngZone.run(() => component.confirmation('Reject'));
    expect(mockService.reject).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because every `if` statement has an imperative else case. This is incase the program exits inside the if true condition. The code coverage is telling you that the final "else" case is untested. You need to add a test that verifies that the dialog does not open if an invalid type is provided.

```js
it('should call reset confirmation dialog', () => {
  setupComponent();
  const dialogService = injector.get(ConfirmationDialogService);
  const dialogServiceSpy = spyOn(dialogService, 'show').and.callThrough();

  component.showMessage = true;
  component.message = 'rejected because potato';
  fixture.ngZone.run(() => component.confirmation('bad-type' as any));
  expect(dialogServiceSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```